# postgres - What could be the dependent objects for a trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, dependencies

Could anyone explain what objects could possibly depend on a trigger in postgres.
Below is the syntax for drop trigger:
DROP TRIGGER [ IF EXISTS ] name ON table [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]

Casdcade/Restrict here impact the dependent objects of a trigger.

I tried creating triggers but failed to see objects that depends on a trigger. Always I see trigger is dependent on other objects such as function, table column but not vice versa.

Can anyone tell me what objects could possibly depend on triggers. Am going to use Cascade option in drop trigger syntax and like to know what kind of object will get impacted.

Thanks,
Vaish

Comment: Why are you adding the cascade in the first place?

Comment: I would like to drop and recreate the trigger and hence want to understand the cascade option in drop trigger syntax. The purpose of my question is to know what objects can be dependent on a trigger.

Comment: I am also trying to understand this. What all objects can depend on a trigger

Answer (score 1):

You can either use pgAdmin to check the dependents/dependencies (just click the object and select the wanted tab in the view)

or

use `\d+ XXXX` on the commandline to see what might depend on it

Comment: Thanks, Yes I did check on pgAdmin too , but could not find any dependents. Do you have any example or idea to know what kind of objects depends on trigger. And for \d+ XXXX command, it works only for tables and not for triggers.